# How to assign a value to a specific mgrid entry in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I am new to matplotlib and scipy. I want to create a two dimensional mgrid in matplotlib and assign individual cells in this two dimensional array to values that I have generated. How can I do it? I am looking for an assignment function such as a[i,j] = k but I cant find one. Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Ranga

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... Are you asking how to assign values to a numpy array? If so, yes, it's just `a[i,j] = value`.  Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do or give a short code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think I found the answer. What I had wanted to do was better done with an numpy.array. So the way to do this (for me) was :

```
    t = []
    zeroRow = []
    for j in range(cols):
        zeroRow.append(0)
    for i in range(rows):
        t.append(zeroRow)
    spectrogramData = np.array(t,float)
```

Later I read the values from a file where the row and column are stored and assign to the spectrogramData

```
   spectrogramData[row][column] = valueRead
```

My confusion was not knowing how to access the wrapped array. It is accessed like any two dimensional array.

Thanks for responding!